# Verify that all getter methods are called

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, junit, mockito

I have the following test where I need to verify that all getters of the Person class are being called. So far I have used mockito's verify() to make sure that each getter is called. Is there a way to do that by reflection? It can be the case that a new getter is added to the Person class but the test will miss that.

```
public class GetterTest {
    class Person{

        private String firstname;
        private String lastname;

        public String getFirstname() {
            return firstname;
        }

        public String getLastname() {
            return lastname;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testAllGettersCalled() throws IntrospectionException{
        Person personMock = mock(Person.class);
        personMock.getFirstname();
        personMock.getLastname();

        for(PropertyDescriptor property : Introspector.getBeanInfo(Person.class).getPropertyDescriptors()) {
            verify(personMock, atLeast(1)).getFirstname();
            //**How to verify against any getter method and not just getFirstName()???**
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally, don't mock the class under test. If your test is for a Person, you shouldn't ever see `Mockito.mock(Person.class)` in it, as that's a pretty clear sign that you're testing the mocking framework instead of the system-under-test.

Instead, you may want to create a `spy(new Person())`, which will create a real Person implementation using a real constructor and then copy its data to a Mockito-generated proxy. You can use `MockingDetails.getInvocations()` to reflectively check that every getter was called.

```
// This code is untested, but should get the point across. Edits welcome.
// 2016-01-20: Integrated feedback from Georgios Stathis. Thanks Georgios!

@Test
public void callAllGetters() throws Exception {
  Person personSpy = spy(new Person());
  personSpy.getFirstname();
  personSpy.getLastname();

  assertAllGettersCalled(personSpy, Person.class);
}

private static void assertAllGettersCalled(Object spy, Class<?> clazz) {
  BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(clazz);
  Set<Method> setOfDescriptors = beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors()
      .stream()
      .map(PropertyDescriptor::getReadMethod)
      .filter(p -> !p.getName().contains("getClass"))
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
  MockingDetails details = Mockito.mockingDetails(spy);
  Set<Method> setOfTestedMethods = details.getInvocations()
      .stream()
      .map(InvocationOnMock::getMethod)
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
  setOfDescriptors.removeAll(setOfTestedMethods);
  // The only remaining descriptors are untested.
  assertThat(setOfDescriptors).isEmpty();
}
```

There might be a way to call `verify` and `invoke` on the Mockito-generated spy, but that seems very fragile, and very dependent on Mockito internals.

As an aside, testing bean-style getters seems like an odd use of time/effort. In general focus on testing implementations that are likely to change or break.

Comment: Great! Regarding your last advice, I think the test is not for Person but for some class like PersonBuilder, PersonCloner or something

Comment: @Raffaele: True, but hopefully the better solution there is to actually check that every field is copied, which implies (but does not require) that every getter was called.

Comment: This actually worked with minimal effort for checking the calling of all getter methods. Some changes though: `BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(Person.class);` and added for `setOfDescriptors` a filter with: `.filter(p -> !p.contains("getClass"))` so that this method is not taken into consideration.

Comment: @GeorgiosStathis Thanks for the feedback! I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two solutions for your problem:

1. Generate the Builder code programmatically, so you don't need to run tests. Java code is generated by a program and never edited by a user. Test the generator instead. Use a text template and build definitions from a serialized domain model or directly from Java compiled classes (you'll need a separate module dependent on the bean's one)
2. Write your tests against a proxy library. The problem is that regular proxies can only implement interfaces, not regular classes, and it's very cumbersome to have interfaces for Javabeans. If you choose this route, I'd go with [Javassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/). I coded a runnable sample and put it [on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/RaffaeleSgarro/84740ae6a0d16d037439). The test cases use a proxy factory to instantiate beans (instead of using `new`)

```
public class CountingCallsProxyFactory {

    public <T> T proxy(Class<T> classToProxy) {
        ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory();
        factory.setSuperclass(classToProxy);
        Class clazz = factory.createClass();
        T instance =  (T) clazz.newInstance();
        ProxyObject proxy = (ProxyObject) instance;
        MethodCallCounter handler = new MethodCallCounter();
        proxy.setHandler(handler);
        return instance;
    }

    public void verifyAllGettersCalled(Object bean) {
        // Query the counter against the properties in the bean
    }
}
```

The counter is kept inside the class `MethodCallCounter`

Comment: Generating the Person builder and then testing the generator seems like a solution. The second one with the proxy objects looks a bit more complicated but I would like to give it a go and try out the Javassist. Thanks for the sample code!

Comment: I favor the generator approach, but again either you use some language other than Java to define both beans and builders, or you'll have at least three compilation modules: the beans, the builders and the app