# Mockito to verify all getter like methods of an interface are called

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

Lets say I have an interface that has many (like 30) getter like methods.

I would like to validate all the methods gets called with out specifying each and every method (that way if the interface gets update we have a failure).

For now I will just write a plain Java proxy handler but I was curious if there was a way to do this in Mockito.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34773497/1426891). May I mark as dupe?

Comment: Yes it appears so :). I feel dumb not being able to google find that. Although I can't recall if BeanInfo works with interfaces. My getter methods were also not true getters because they were not prefixed with get.

Comment: No worries! Not always easy to find. Hopefully the answer there will work with a few reflective adjustments to `getMethods` instead of using BeanInfo.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using a Proxy. I figured I would post it for others.
It is not elegant but it works.

One could add additional validate methods like sub or super set validation of methods instead of an exact match.

```java
@Test
public void test() {
    VerifyAllMethods h = new VerifyAllMethods() {
        @Override
        public Object runMethod(Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            Class<?> rt = method.getReturnType();
            if (Optional.class.equals(rt)) {
                return Optional.absent();
            }
            else if (String.class.equals(rt)) {
                return "mock";
            }
            else if (Integer.class.equals(rt)) {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (List.class.equals(rt)) {
                return Lists.newArrayList("1");
            }
            else {
                return rt.newInstance();
            }
        }
    };

    SomeInterface mf = h.mock(SomeInterface.class);

  // do something with SomeInterface    

    h.validateEquals(SomeInterface.class);

}

public abstract static class VerifyAllMethods implements InvocationHandler {
    private final Set<Method> actualMethods = Sets.newLinkedHashSet();

    public VerifyAllMethods() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        actualMethods.add(method);
        return runMethod(method, args);

    }

    public abstract Object runMethod(Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable;

    public Set<Method> getActualMethods() {
        return actualMethods;
    }

    public void validateEquals(Class<?> iface) {
        Set<Method> methods = Sets.newHashSet(iface.getMethods());
        /*
         * Asserting Equals on strings is better for IDE as
         * most generate a diff.
         */
        assertEquals(methodsToString(methods), methodsToString(actualMethods));
    }

    public String methodsToString(Iterable<Method> methods) {
        List<String> names = Lists.newArrayList();
        for (Method m : methods) {
            names.add(m.toString());
        }
        Collections.sort(names);
        return Joiner.on("\n").join(names);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T mock(Class<T> iface) {
        actualMethods.clear();
        Class<?>[] interfaces = {iface};
        return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(getClass().getClassLoader(), interfaces , this);
    }

}
```